# WHOIS BASH Script sometimes not fetching data

Tags: linux, bash

My whois bash script works for a few domains and doesn't for others.

When I run the command directly in my terminal for the same domain, I am able to see output. Also, sometimes  the script will not run properly and gets stuck, then I need to interrupt that.

Why is that, and how can I fix it?

Let's say the `domain.txt` file contains: gmail.com, zoom.us, facebook.com, bank.com etc.

The script is:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
echo "Please enter the full path of txt file"
read path
filename=$path
while read line
do
    echo "Checking domain $line"
    a=$(whois $line | grep -i -e "Creation Date" | head -1)
    b=$(whois $line | grep -i -e "no match" | head -1)
    echo "$a"$line >> /root/outputdomain.csv
done <$filename
echo "file has been processed successfully."
```

A sample input txt file is:

```
linkedin.com
zoom.us
sbi.co.in
facebook.com
sap.com
hsbc.com
```

Expected Output is:

```
Creation Date: 2002-11-02T15:38:11Z linkedin.com
Creation Date: 2002-04-24T15:03:39Z zoom.us
```

Whats is working for me currently:

```
Creation Date: 2002-11-02T15:38:11Z linkedin.com
Creation Date: 1997-03-29T05:00:00Z facebook.com
```

But no output for zoom.us, sbi.co.in.

If I run the command below, I am able to fetch the required data:

```
$ whois zoom.us | grep -E "Creation Date" | head -1
Creation Date: 2002-04-24T15:03:39Z
```

Comment: Please post a sample input file and the output you expected/want

Comment: example input txt file content is: zoom.us sbi.co.in

Comment: Update your question and add it in your post.

Comment: basically the reason of this script development is to read input as 100 of domains from text file and fetch creation date value and if creation date field not present then it should return no domain match.

Comment: Waht if you use: grep -Fi  "creation date" | head -1

Comment: Try this  `grep --line-buffer  -Fi -m1   'creation date'`

Comment: The script should work as it is. Did you try to debug it `set -x` and see on which command it stops?

Comment: It might be a buffering issue.

Comment: `whois` sometimes times-out with no output. Check `$PIPESTATUS` in your code.

Comment: @Jetchisel, how could this possibly be a buffering issue? Buffers are flushed on exit, and the copy of `grep` exits before the command substitution is evaluated.

Comment: Your code will complete faster if you run `whois` once, save the answer and then run `grep` on that, rather than running `whois` twice. Also, you don't use `$b` so that line is useless anyway.

Comment: Actually, I could see the whois server one is contacting rate-limiting excessive inbound connections, so halving the number of requests may go a distance towards solving the underlying issue.

Comment: That's why I have added a sleep in my script but It still timeouts ...

Comment: Halve the number of connections, and you'll need less of a `sleep`. Beyond that, just detect the failure and retry.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use/know `whois` but base on your post this is what I came up with.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

shopt -s extglob
echo "Please enter the full path of txt file"
read -r path
filename=$path
while read -r line; do
  printf 'Processing %s\n' "$line"...
  if a=$(whois "$line" | grep --line-buffer -Fi -m1 "creation date"); then
    printf '%s %s\n' "${a##*+([[:blank:]])}" "$line" >> outputdomain.csv
  else
    printf  '%s No domain match\n' "$line" >> outputdomain.csv
  fi
  sleep 5
done < "$filename"
```

- `-m` Might not be POSIX but it is in `GNU` and `BSD` grep.

Comment: Don't think this will fix the problem - which is that `whois` command itself is timing-out with no output.

Comment: What's the point of `extglob` here? And I don't see why the buffering option in grep would matter, since you're letting it run to completion inside a command substitution -- buffers *always* get flushed on graceful exit. Selecting line buffering makes it print output a little earlier, but that also means you're paying to call the `write()` syscall *more frequently*, until waiting until exit and writing everything at once; this is exactly the kind of situation that the performance optimization of using larger-than-one-line buffers is made for.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy just to remove the leading spaces

Comment: Ahh, now that you point it out, I see the `extglob` use in the parameter-expansion context. That's fair -- recent enough bash versions *always* support extglobs in PE context, but better to be compatible with older ones that require the flag.